# Efficient search of a phone number between several columns in the table

Tags: sql-server

My table has 4 columns: Customer name, phone 1, phone 2, phone 3.

I need to check if a particular phone number exists in one of the three columns.

My table looks like this: `Customerֹ_table`

| Customer name | phone 1 | phone 2 | phone 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MOP | 123454678 | 2345556789 | 346757890 |
| AVI | 456735673 | 3453546354 | 235634563 |
| DEN | 125345678 | 2345635635 | 123454678 |

Here's the query I wrote -

```
  SELECT DISTINCT COUSTMER_NAME
  FROM Customerֹ_table 
  WHERE NUM_1 OR NUM_2 OR NUM_3 OR NUM_4 =  xxxxxxxxx
```

Is it right to do the query like that? I am looking for the maximum efficiency possible.

Comment: Your data model is not built for maximum efficiency, your phone numbers should be in a `phone_numbers` table with a migrated key from your customer `Id`

Comment: Can you explain a little more?

Comment: Use an `IN`? But ideally you should normalise the design.

Comment: Also, for your table really have that non standard `rֹ` character in its name?

Comment: Normalisation was important back when hard drives were small but I don't think its still needed in 2021, particularly as we move toward Microservices.

Comment: As I read the comments, I wondered if Geoff G is a blowhard or an expert since he did not provide sources. I am no expert but I can assure you that I have anecdotally observed what Geoff asserts time and again. SQL server does "learn" as it goes.  At first I thought it was just caching query results so that if you reran the query, it could give you in half a second what took 20 seconds the first time, but I observed that I could change the query in significant ways and it still only took a fraction of a second, after the painful first pass. dynamic indexes would explain that. I think he knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore what others have said about redesigning your data structure, this absolutely will not help in SQL Server. Maybe in Oracle or MySQL whatever, but SQL Server is smart enough to use a flat table structure like you have efficiently.

Here are the Top 4 ways to improve the efficiency of your query:

**One:** Use GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT. DISTINCT is a real performance killer and shouldn't ever be used if you want efficient code. It's a nice shorthand hacky way of getting a unique result, but use GROUP BY for performance.

**Two:** Use WITH(NOLOCK) to speed up your table read. This can be controversial, but it really shouldn't be. SQL Server 2017 and beyond have lots of nice safety features which make legacy concerns about using NOLOCK for analysis null and void.

**Three:** Make one of the columns in your data table a PRIMARY KEY. This is important for all kinds of reasons, but in particular performance. SQL Server relies on having a Primary Key so that its automatic performance enhancements and dynamic query optimisation plans can work. In general, the more often you run a query against a table with a Primary Key, the faster SQL will get at delivering you results.

**Four:** Once you've added a Primary Key, add a separate Nonclustered index for each of your Telephone Number columns. If your table is very large, this would speed up the query a lot. Bear in mind that adding indexes on a very large table takes up a lot of disk space.

Ideally your CUSTOMER_NAME field would be unique, so you could make that your primary key. If it isn't, you'll need to add an ID column as per Yitzhak Khabinsky's answer.

So your query would look like this:

```
  SELECT COUSTMER_NAME
    FROM Customerֹ_table WITH(NOLOCK)
   WHERE NUM_1 OR NUM_2 OR NUM_3 OR NUM_4 = xxxxxxxxx
GROUP BY COUSTMER_NAME
```

Assuming the table's Primary Key is on the COUSTMER_NAME column.

For bonus points:

Make sure *all* columns in your data table are set to NOT NULL. SQL Server will attempt to create dynamic indexes to help speed up your queries, but it won't do so on any columns flagged as nullable. The only exceptions are dates, where you often have no option but to allow for NULLs, so have to take the performance hit.

Use Varchars and not NVarchars. Unless you have some reason to use an NVarchar, like you are capturing extended characters like Chinese, Arabic etc, then don't. They take up twice the space, take longer to scan and take longer to perform logic on such as matching a value in your WHERE clause

Keep your column lengths as short as reasonably possible. So if a Telephone number can only ever be 20 digits long, then set that column to 25 or maybe 30 digits max, just in case you start getting longer phone numbers in the future. If you know your customer ID is only ever going to be 3 digits long, set that field to max 3 digits. Keeping the max size of your data tables trimmed down to the minimum (while leaving enough overhead to reasonably cope with future requirements) really helps with performance.

Comment: A lot of good stuff in here, but won't help when a OP has to add a fifth phone number to a customer.

Comment: This would be pretty easy, just create a Customer_Table2 with the 5th phone number column, select all data from Customer_Table into it, delete Customer_Table, rename Customer_Table2 to Customer_Table. Done.

Comment: I would disagree with most of that - if you need distinct then using group by instead is not going to magically speed the query up - it will yield an identical execution plan. `nolock` should never be used in this context, it can have unpredicatable side-effects such as skip rows and duplicate data. Sql Server does not "dynamically create indexes" - or can you point me to the documentation on this feature?

Comment: @GeoffGriswald what you seem to be saying is, don't bother worry about the first principle of database design (normalization) because this one particular DBMS will (probably) take care of it, under the covers, in this one particular use case. Which, for all I know might be true, but I don't think it's the best advice to give to someone who's looking for advice on how to get data out of a table with four columns and three rows.

Comment: That's pretty much the size of it yes. The question was "How do I do this efficiently in SQL Server, given my current database design", not "What's the best-practise way to do this in any DBMS following the first principles of database design and redesigning any database I might already have". One of the most powerful features of SQL Server is being able to get great performance from queries against flat tables, which is, 99% of the time, normally what users will want to query.

Comment: @Stu sorry that you still think NOLOCK shouldn't be used. This hasn't been true in SQL Server since 2017. For analytics queries such as this one, NOLOCK is an ideal way to improve query speed. Sorry also that you don't understand the performance difference between DISTINCT and GROUP BY. There are many articles online explaining the performance difference between those two functions in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, customer NVARCHAR(20), phone1 VARCHAR(10), phone2 VARCHAR(10), phone3 VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @tbl (customer, phone1, phone2, phone3) VALUES
(N'MOP', '123454678', '2345556789', '346757890'),
(N'AVI', '456735673', '3453546354', '235634563'),
(N'DEN', '125345678', '2345635635', '123454678');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @phone VARCHAR(10) = '2345635635';

SELECT * 
FROM @tbl
WHERE @phone IN (phone1, phone2, phone3);
```

**Output**

```
+----+----------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| ID | customer |  phone1   |   phone2   |  phone3   |
+----+----------+-----------+------------+-----------+
|  3 | DEN      | 125345678 | 2345635635 | 123454678 |
+----+----------+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: WHERE @phone IN is an inherently inefficient way to do that. Better to have a WHERE clause with three OR statements.

Answer (score 1):

For the best performance, you need to normalise your data - this would allow you to have not just 3 phone numbers but any number - you can add a flag to soft delete, indicate a primary number etc, it's much more manageable than adding N columns in a flat table.

Add a PhoneNumbers table - a bare bones table might be

```
create table PhoneNumbers (
    customerId int,
    PhoneNumber varchar(20),
    ... any other related data - eg a flag to indicate the primary number etc
)

alter table Phonenumber add constraint PK_PhoneNumbers primary key nonclustered (CustomerId, Phonenumber)
create unique clustered index IdxCustomerId on (Phonenumber,CustomerId)
```

Then to find a customer with a specific number

```
select c.CustomerName
from PhoneNumbers n
join Customers c on c.customerId=n.customerId 
where n.Phonenumber='12345678'
```

Comment: "need to?", no. SQL Server will deliver fast performance even with a flat table structure. It's "best practise" to normalise the data like this, but it is by no means necessary to unlock good query performance.

Comment: @GeoffGriswald I disagree - while obviously both solutions work, normalising the data in this fashion is guaranteed to give better performance especially as the data grows, it requires a single index seek to find *any* number; by needing to search N columns and using or to match on those columns, an index seek is not possible, likely sql server will have to scan the table or at best scan an index covering the columns.

Comment: Correct, except that SQL Server will intelligently create a dynamic index for each of the phone number columns, so after a few runs of the query on a flat table structure, it would be just as fast if not faster than the normalised structure, and without the added complexity and loss of coherence in the data that normalising brings. Also, there's nothing stopping you from creating additional nonclustered indexes on each of the phone number columns, which would do the same thing in a more predictable way.

Comment: @GeoffGriswald are you confusing indexes with statistics?

Comment: No, for very large queries the query optimiser will create dynamic indexes as part of the execution plan, provided you have primary keys on all tables in your query and there is no other appropriate index to use.

Comment: @GeoffGriswald would be kind enough to point me to the details of that particular feature, I can't seem to find anything?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/automatic-tuning/automatic-tuning?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @GeoffGriswald I did wonder if you were referring to this - automatic index generation is only a feature - currently - for *Azure*; in Sql Server 2017+ it's limited to automatically forcing a last-known good plan and addressing some query plan optimisations.

Comment: In any case, "redesign your tables to match this arbitrary design that someone decided back in the 1980s was the 'correct' design" is not a good answer. "use WITH(NOLOCK)", "use GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT" and "Add indexes" is the type of advice that will improve query performance without requiring the user to blow up what they already have.

Answer (score 0):

For "maximum efficiency" you need to do what Stu said and redesign your database structure. Meanwhile, here's a query that will work with your existing database structure.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER_NAME
FROM Customerֹ_table 
WHERE NUM_1 = xxxxxxxxx
OR NUM_2 = xxxxxxxxx
OR NUM_3 = xxxxxxxxx
OR NUM_4 = xxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Can you expand a little on inefficiency? Or alternatively how to do it right? thanks

Comment: You need at lease two tables. The customer name goes in the customer table and the phone numbers go in a phone number table. You establish a one-to-many relationship between the two tables using a [foreign key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-ver15),

Comment: Oh
It's my mistake ...
I wrote a customer name instead of a customer ID.
But thank you, I understood better thanks to you!

Comment: Sorry this is not correct. Having two tables in this example is less efficient than one table with 4 columns.

Comment: @GeoffGriswald in this example, a table with four columns and three rows, the most efficient solution would be an index card in the shirt pocket.

Comment: I have to assume that OPs table has more than three rows, and he didn't want to copy and paste 10 million rows into his StackOverflow question. Otherwise he would not be asking about query efficiency.